# Hide the Partial view and show another partial view in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a hyperlink column in the grid. On clicking the link i have to hide the partialview(grid section) and have to show/load another partialview which is the detail section. Please provide solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript. With jQuery that will correspond to the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function or the [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) functions. So basically you will subscribe to the click event of the link and inside this handler show and hide the respective sections. For this to work you should obviously place those partials inside placeholder divs so that you could show/hide the entire placeholder.

If in addition to showing the partial you need to fetch some fresh information from the server then you could use AJAX to request a controller action that will return the fresh data of the partial view that you will inject into the DOM at the correct placeholder location. In order to send an AJAX request in jQuery you could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function or directly the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.